# How to prevent pandas dataframe to shirk string value to [...] after appending ?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, truncate

I use list of list to create dataframe in short with this code below, but I got result of df with `"..."` value after put the value in dataframe for example :

http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.1...

if I get value from actual "`lists`" I can still print full   `http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.1.1.html`

but how can I prevent `df[0]` to return value of `http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.1...`

```
lists = []
    for i in tables : 
        list = []
        link = http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.1.1.html
        list.append(link)
        list.append(othervalue)
    lists.append(list)

df = pd.DataFrame(lists)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only display problem. You need `display.max_colwidth` set to some higher `int`, e.g. `100`, see [`available options`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available):

```
#temporaly set max_colwidth to 100
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 100):
    print (df)
                                                       0   1
0  http://shakespeare.mit.edu/allswell/allswell.1.1.html  aa
```